# running a class at the starting of spring-mvc application

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc

is it possible to run a class at the time of application starting in spring mvc
i want to initialize a thread in that class  ??

or is there any way..?

```
                public class MyServletContextListener implements Runnable {



            public void run() {

                while (true) {

                try {
                    System.out.println("Inside run()");
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }


            }

            }
```

this output i got after adding ApplicationListener interface

```
            NFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:33 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
            INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:35 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
            INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
            INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4

            Thread Started
            getApplicationName() : /Hibernate_webservice
            getId() : org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:/Hibernate_webservice
            getParent() : null
            getDisplayName() : Root WebApplicationContext


            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:38 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
            INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8880 ms
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
            INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
            INFO: FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:38 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
            INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Mon Jul 24 20:42:38 IST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
            INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties
            INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [application.properties]
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
            INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
            INFO: Mapped "{[/form],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView sample.test.TestController.method()
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:39 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
            INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
            INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4

            Thread Started
            getApplicationName() : /Hibernate_webservice
            getId() : org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:/Hibernate_webservice/appServlet
            getParent() : Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jul 24 20:42:30 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
            getDisplayName() : WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet'



            Thread Started
            getApplicationName() : /Hibernate_webservice
            getId() : org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:/Hibernate_webservice/appServlet
            getParent() : Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jul 24 20:42:30 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
            getDisplayName() : WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet'


            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:39 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
            INFO: FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 1365 ms
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
            INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
            INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8011"]
            Jul 24, 2017 8:42:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
            INFO: Server startup in 19807 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring provides the `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` interface and its `onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event)` hook.

For example:

```
@Component
public class MyServiceCreationListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
      // do something on container startup
    }
}
```

Whatever you write in `onApplicationEvent` method will be executed once and only once when the Spring context is created.

If you find that this method is invoked more than once then you must have multiple `ApplicationContext`'s at play. If you inspect `event.getApplicationContext()` you'll likely see that each of them have a different id and displayName and you may be able to work out their origins. If yours is a Spring MVC application then you may have both a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`, both of these create their own `ApplicationContext` each of which fires a `ContextRefreshedEvent`.

If you want to determine which is the parent context you could try `event.getApplicationContext().getParent() != null` or you could toggle a class boolean within your ApplicationListener e.g. `alreadyInitialised`.

There's also Spring 4's [SmartInitializingSingleton](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/SmartInitializingSingleton.html) which might allow you to hook into context creation at a different level.

Comment: this solution is working but it call onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) 3 times when application loads

Comment: I have updated the answer to describe how ContextRefreshedEvent could be fired multiple times and to offer some suggestions for how to avoid/handle that.

Comment: is it good to having multiple application contexts...what should i have to do if i want only one context??

Comment: Some Spring components start up child application contexts, from the perspective of a Spring user this is neither good nor bad i.e. it is not something for you to worry about. However, it will result in multiple ContextRefreshedEvents being fired and hence an ApplicationListener in the root context being triggered multiple times. If this is an issue for you then you must either code your listener such that it handles only one of these invocations (either use a class boolean to control it or only bind to the event received from the parent context) or else use a SmartInitializingSingleton.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an application listener (A class implements a context listener interface ) to create your thread with no headache
If you are creating time schedule you can use quartz or spring timer

Answer (score 2):

As of Spring 4.2 you can simply use the `@EventListener` annotation, listening for `ContextRefreshedEvent`:

```
@Component
public class StartupManager {

    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void doStartupStuff() {
        // ... up, up and away
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple Java thread by extending Thread, and managed by Spring’s container via `@Component.` The bean scope must be “prototype“, so that each request will return a new instance, to run each individual thread.

```
PrintThread.java:

package com.mkyong.thread;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class PrintThread extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println(getName() + " is running");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(getName() + " is running");
    }

}

AppConfig.java:

package com.mkyong.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.mkyong.thread")
public class AppConfig{
}

App.java:

package com.mkyong;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.mkyong.config.AppConfig;
import com.mkyong.thread.PrintThread;

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

        PrintThread printThread1 = (PrintThread) ctx.getBean("printThread");
        printThread1.setName("Thread 1");

        PrintThread printThread2 = (PrintThread) ctx.getBean("printThread");
        printThread2.setName("Thread 2");

        PrintThread printThread3 = (PrintThread) ctx.getBean("printThread");
        printThread3.setName("Thread 3");

        PrintThread printThread4 = (PrintThread) ctx.getBean("printThread");
        printThread4.setName("Thread 4");

        PrintThread printThread5 = (PrintThread) ctx.getBean("printThread");
        printThread5.setName("Thread 5");

        printThread1.start();
        printThread2.start();
        printThread3.start();
        printThread4.start();
        printThread5.start();

    }
}
```

Output – The order will be vary each time, this is thread :)

```
Thread 3 is running
Thread 2 is running
Thread 1 is running
Thread 5 is running
Thread 4 is running
Thread 2 is running
Thread 4 is running
Thread 5 is running
Thread 3 is running
Thread 1 is running
```

**hope this is helpful :)**